# What launch program is WeMeetRoomsDaemon?

Tags: macos, launchd

I just purchased a new mac book pro computer and transferred the information from my old computer. The first thing I saw was notifications popping up saying that programs are being setup to run in the background. One of the programs was WeMeetRoomsDaemon. When I click on the item it just leads me to the Launch Daemon file. This is really weird to me as there is a separate launch daemon file already and I don't have any application related to the name: "WeMeetRooms". Can anyone explain what this means? Thanks.[image]

Comment: Is the file a text plist? There should be a developer ID and name to it (often reverse domain name so a Facebook daemon might be com.facebook.something.else ) This is by design to show you every thing that was installed on the old Mac - so it's likely you can trace it there, too and not that it's something new.